# ViewFlipper is causing Null Pointer Exception with animation

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am making a calculator app that of course has lots of buttons specifically imagebuttons in my case. The app works in 2.3 but cause issues for 4.0. The issue is that I get a NullPointerException with my ViewFlipper showing the next view.

```
phhistbnt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
    try
    {
        vib.vibrate(30);

        if(animChoice == 0)
            vf1.showNext(); // issue here and most likely the rest of them
        else if(animChoice == 1)
        {
            vf1.setOutAnimation(topUp);
            vf1.showNext();
            vf1.setInAnimation(Fl);
        }
        else if(animChoice == 2)
        {
            vf1.setOutAnimation(fadeOut2);
            vf1.showNext();
            vf1.setInAnimation(hy);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
});
```

Here is LogCat:

```
08-18 21:55:29.301: W/System.err(6141): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 21:55:29.301: W/System.err(6141):     at
f7Calc.com.KidzCalcActivity$12.onClick(CalcActivity.java:751)    
08-18 21:55:29.301: W/System.err(6141): at 
android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
08-18 21:55:29.301: W/System.err(6141): at      
android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at     
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at  
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at  
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-18 21:55:29.311: W/System.err(6141):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   
Method)
```

In the emulator, Logcat will show:

```
08-18 22:19:25.144: I/Choreographer(1290): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be   
doing too much work on its main thread.
```

but it continue to work as usual. 
I have started to use AsyncTask but I am unsure how to use it. Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `vf1` could be null if you are using a seperate layout for devices running 4.0+. Maybe that layout does not contain that View or it's id is different. I know this is unlikely but it's the only thing thats comming to my mind right now.

Comment: I have one layout for both 2.3 and 4.0. All of my resources that are for other screen sizes have the same ids as the rest unless its for an Tablet. Installing the app on the tablet is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out with the help of Paul. Before upgrade to ICE 4.0.x, I had to resize in code the buttons for a screen size that had 960x540 resolution because there was no layout for that screen size. Apparently when I had upgraded my phone to ICE (Evo 3D), ICE uses the layout-sw360dp layout for 960x540 instead of nothing at all. After adding that to the list of layouts and entering in the corrected IDs need for the activity, walla, it works.